Home invasion gone wrong: burglar accidentally breaks father's neck
The following text contains descriptions of mature and possibly disturbing content.
When I was a child (early 2000s), I was shocked by a movie I saw while secretly watching TV late at night. It was the German version of a foreign, probably North American, movie about a home invasion. I do not remember a lot, but the following things stayed in my head: 

Burglars enter the house of a family of at least four (mother, father, son, daughter)
At some point the son is raped to death (even now, I have no idea how this made it through the very strict censorship we have here in Germany)
At some point one of the burglars keeps the father in a headlock, does not pay attention to him while still holding him and accidentally breaks the father's neck
I am not entirely sure, but I think the daughter is the last survivor. I do not remember if she lives or not. 

There may or may not:

be a showdown at the rooftop. 
be a baby that's part of the family

I understand those details are very vague, but maybe somebody reckognizes the movie I am talking about.

"I have no idea how this made it through the very strict censorship we have here in Germany" - Compared to where, the U.S.? Surely not.

Sounds a lot Michael Haneke's "Funny Games".
He's made this movie twice (http://www.imdb.com/find?q=funny+games, top two results): first in 1997 in Austria and then, 10 years later, a shot-by-shot remake in US, with Tim Roth and Naomi Watts.
Similarities:

it was made in Austria and then in US (as opposed to US and then Germany)
it's about home invasion gone disturbingly wrong
family's son is brutally killed
last surviving person is female

But:

the family is of three: father, mother and son
I can't remember son being raped to death. He is killed off-screen, blood splatters on a TV screen.
I can't remember how the father died (that neck-breaking thing).
spoiler (ending):


 no one survives in the end (although the mother dies last)

Maybe check the trailers (you can find them on YouTube and wow, even the trailers are remade shot by shot!) and see if it's it. I think you can even find the whole movie on YouTube.
If it's not that, maybe you'll remember something more and we'll keep looking :)

It's called "If I Die Before I Wake," I had been looking to remember what it was called for the longest time too: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137827/

I wish you'd elaborate, because this does seem like a closer match than Funny Games.
